# How to change the many to many relationship format in drf

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is my serializer class

```
class ProjectSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    created_by = SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='email')
    updated_by = SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='email')
    team = SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='first_name')
    class Meta:
       model = Project
       exclude = ['deleted_at']
```

This is Models.py

```
class Project(MandatoryFields, Model):  
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    project_areas = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    team = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_team")
    project_manager = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_project_manager")       
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

I am getting response like this

```
"status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created_by": "abc@google.com",
            "updated_by": "abc@google.com",
            "project_manager": "abc@google.com",
            "team": ["Rahul",
             "Anoop",
             ],
            "created_date": "2020-01-16T05:18:58.471601Z",
            "modified_date": "2020-01-16T05:18:58.471662Z",
            "project_name": "ABC",
            "project_areas": "ABC",
            "start_date": null,
            "end_date": null,
        },
```

My issue is the team is a many to many relationship with user model. I need to change the response of the field team . It need to return the id and the name in a dictionary format.

How can I change this

```
 "team": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Rahul",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Anoop",
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a ***[Nested Serializer (`TeamSerializer`)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)*** and wire-up it in your **`ProjectSerializer`** as,

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source='first_name')

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('id', 'name')


class ProjectSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    created_by = SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='email')
    updated_by = SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='email')
    team = TeamSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude = ['deleted_at']
```

I have used [**`source`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument too here, which used to specify the source of  data to be pulled off.

---

### Update-1

Use **`SerializerMethodField`**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('id', 'name')

    def get_name(self, user):
        return '{} {}'.format(user.first_name, user.last_name)
```

Comment: name = serializers.CharField(source='first_name')

Hey how to add both first name and last name?

Comment: Currently I am getting only first name

Comment: Do you need a concatenated result? or in different fields?

Comment: Concatinate the result

Comment: "team": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Rahul Dravid",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Sachin Tendulkar",
        }
    ],

Comment: In the above 
Rahul is first name 

Dravid is the last name 

But I need to pass it as a name Rahul Dravid

Comment: Use [**`SerializerMethodField(...)`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Comment: class TeamSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    """
    Displaying Team Members in Dictionary Format
    """

    name = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        
    def name(self, obj):
        return (obj.first_name+ obj.last_name)

Comment: Like this ?

Could you please help me to fix it ?

It shows some error

Comment: How to use Use SerializerMethodField(...) in my case ?

Comment: Check my update. (Humble suggestion, Do not c&p your whole codebase into a comment section)